# Weighting variables with high variance

Tags: data-transformation

For context - I'm the data analyst for a start-up company that compares car lease deals.

I want to create an algorithm which uses weighted variables to rank the best deals based on various criteria.

One of the variables is the popularity of the vehicle, i.e. the number of orders received in the last X days, 90 in this case.

I take the % split of orders on each vehicle against the total, leaving a top-heavy distribution of 443 observations, with the 30 most popular models receiving the same number of orders as the 413 least popular.

I want to give higher weights to the most popular models, without making the rest irrelevant.

[image: Distribution of orders]

The STDEV = 54 and variance = 2,919. Mean = 26.8 and median = 6

What transformation could I apply to these values to bring them closer together, thus reducing the weight given to the variable when included in the algorithm? If more information is needed, let me know :) Thanks

Comment: "Statistical significance" and "rank" just don't go together because they are associated with *completely* different problems.  That leads me to wonder what you are really trying to accomplish.

Comment: @whuber I guess I need to learn the terminology before throwing it around. I think I just mean weight? as in I want to weight each vehicle based on its popularity, without nullifying the less popular vehicles - so that if a vehicle with 1 order in the last 3 months suddenly dropped in price it wouldn't be ignored solely based on popularity. I hope that makes sense

Comment: I agree with @whuber in that your question could be more clear. Are you asking about how to capture each model's popularity (creating a new variable) or about how to weigh model popularity in your ranking algorithm? Or both? These are completely different problems.

Comment: @AdriàLuz would I be wrong to suppose both approaches could solve my issue - that issue being the disproportionate weighting of vehicle model based on its popularity? could the new variable not be used in the ranking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing here from the comments discussion...

The way I see it, there are two different challenges that you'll need to tackle:

1. How do you capture / measure model popularity? That is, how do you create a metric that is higher for more popular models and lower for less popular ones?
2. How do you weigh model popularity in the ranking, relative to other relevant features (e.g. price)?

For 1., a simple approach would be to take the number of orders received by each model and do [min-max normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling#Rescaling_(min-max_normalization)). This way, the most popular model would get a "popularity score" of 1 and the least popular model would get a "popularity score" of 0. Every other model would get a score between 0 and 1.

Solving 2. is potentially more complex, so I would need more details to be able to say anything useful. What other features do you want the ranking to take into consideration? It sounds like price might be one of those features and, based on what you've said, it seems like you believe that it should have more weight relative to the popularity of the model.

Mathematically:
$$r_i=w_1v_{i1}+w_2v_{i2}+\cdots+w_pv_{ip}$$
where $r_i$ is the ranking score for model $i$, $w_p$ is the weight for variable $p$, and $v_{ip}$ is model's $i$ actual value of the variable $p$. For example, a ranking algorithm that only considered model popularity and price might look something like this:
$$r_i=0.3\operatorname{popularity}_i-0.7\operatorname{price}_i$$
Then you could rank by $r_i$ in descending order. You can see that the real challenge is to work out how to properly define the weights.  In the past, I have used a combination of design of experiments and discrete choice modelling to find weights for ranking problems. Both are explained in [this paper](https://www.jstatsoft.org/index.php/jss/article/view/v050c02/v50c02.pdf).

Comment: This is really useful, thank you for breaking it down. Could you recommend a guide, or if that's wishful thinking, some literature to help me better understand - and eventually implement - such weights?

Comment: @AlexMidmore In the past, I have used a combination of design of experiments and discrete choice modelling to find weights for ranking problems. Both are explained in [this paper](https://www.jstatsoft.org/index.php/jss/article/view/v050c02/v50c02.pdf).